# Problem with QTableWidget.scrollToItem functionality

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtablewidget, scrollto

struggling with a problem:

I'm using that function for the initial positioning view to the center of a large table.

By creating a QTableWidget object when the app is just loaded,
and filling the table with new data (including new cols/rows) before showing it:
(by pressing button)

```
...
self.table.scrollToItem(self.tabl.item(central_row, 0), QAbstractItemView.PositionAtCenter)
self.table_ticker.scrollToItem(self.table.selectRow(central_row), QAbstractItemView.PositionAtCenter)
...
```

So, there are 2 problems for me that I cant understand:

1. the positioning doesn't work correctly for the 1st time of calling,
   but only from the 2nd time (by pressing the button) or more.
   Sometimes and a 1st time there is only a couple of columns are visible.
   I guess QTableWidget requires some internal update to etc, I tried this:

   ```
        self.table.updateGeometry()
        self.table.update()
        self.table.updateEditorGeometries()
   ```

   but it doesn't help.
2. I don't need to make any selection like this above:

> `self.table.selectRow(central_row)`

but without this trick, the positioning doesn't work at all.
Of course, I can do clearSelection, but
are there any other ways to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Centering on the item view during initialization is something that rarely works, as at that point the widgets are not mapped yet and their area might still change lots of time until the window is finally shown. Have you tried with a singleshot timer? `QTimer.singleshot(0, self.functionThatCenters)` (note that all those `update*()` calls are completely unnecessary if the widget is not yet shown)

Comment: thanx fo the idea,
self.timer.timeout.connect(lambda: self.PosAtCenter())
solved all.